# why this wpf data binding fails

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I'm a newer to study Wpf Data Binding feature, and recently I met one problem puzzled me a lot.

Assume we have some code like this in ViewModel:

```
private Person person;    
public Person Person
{
    get { return person; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty<Person>(ref person, ref value, ()=>Person);
    }
}
```

*Ignore the terrible naming*. Then I changed the `Person` property as following in Command's Execute() method:

```
//try 1
private void UpdateInfoExecute()
{
     Person.Name="somebody";
     Person.Age=22;
}
```

Finally, the data binding failed. As I change the implementation like this:

```
//try 2
Person = new Models.Person() { Age=22,Name="somebody"};
```

It succeed!

Well, in my opinion, **try 1** also changed `Person`'s property just like **try 2** do. The `PropertyChanged` event listen on `Person` property, and sure it would be changed after **try 1** did.

I don't know the theory of this, can anyone point me the key I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly SetProperty does, but in your "try1" you are changing Name and Age, not Person. So Name and Age properties are raised, the reference of Person was not changed and stayed the same. In your "try2" you actually set a new Person, therefore the property was changed and raised.

Solution: Make sure that Person also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and make sure that each property raises a `PropertyChanged`. Then everything should work fine.

Remember `.Person` is like `.Name` just a property.

Comment: **the reference of Person was not changed and stayed the same.** -- that's what I am looking for, thanks a lot.